# conan install unbuilt dependencies encountering series of problems

Tags: qt, cmake, conan

**Scenario**:

I want to install Qt using conan install.
I simply list `qt/6.3.0` in `[requires]` section in my `conanfile.txt`.

Since Qt isn't a pre-built lib, so I use this command after a few failed attempts.

```
sudo conan install .. --build=missing
```

I use `sudo` because it's necessary to build those dependencies, or it will fail because some permissions are denied during the installation.

**Problem**:

Using `sudo` causes dependencies being installed in `/root/.conan` folder. Then all built procedures will also need `sudo` because you need to access those dependencies. It's very inconvenient.

**Question**:

So, either run the command in user mode, or set the dependency install folder to `<user>/.conan` under super-user mode and open the files' permission for `<user>`. But I don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `sudo` to call `conan` command.

The `sudo` operation seems necessary for the system package manager. Checking the available configurations with `conan config list` we see:

```
$ conan config list
...
tools.system.package_manager:mode: Mode for package_manager tools: 'check' or 'install'
tools.system.package_manager:sudo: Use 'sudo' when invoking the package manager tools in Linux (False by default)
tools.system.package_manager:sudo_askpass: Use the '-A' argument if using sudo in Linux to invoke the system package manager (False by default)
tools.system.package_manager:tool: Default package manager tool:
```

You can control and request usage of `sudo` just for the system package manager with `tools.system.package_manager:sudo`

Comment: Still failed. Error msg: conanfile.txt: ERROR: Generator txt(file:conanbuildinfo.txt) failed. [ERROR 13] Permission denied: '<my_project_path>/build/conanbuildinfo.txt'

Comment: And I find it weird that the process failed after qt has been built & installed.

Comment: You might need to clean first your local project ``build`` folder, that still has ``root`` permissions, and you are now trying to overwrite it from non-sudo permissions. It is failing at creating some local files in your user folder, indeed qt is fine in the cache, but it failed to create the local files in your folder. Make sure to clean your environment, and the conan cache (so packages are not under the sudo permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

Just for record:

First, set `conanfile.txt`.
Then,
run

```
mkdir build
cd build
conan install .. --build=missing
```

this command will build & install Qt.
But after installation, the procedure fails because of Permission Error.

```
conanfile.txt: ERROR: Generator txt(file:conanbuildinfo.txt) failed. 
[ERROR 13] Permission denied: '<my_project_path>/build/conanbuildinfo.txt'
```

Then delete whole `build` folder and re-build with

```
conan install ..
```

Because qt has been installed, so you don't need to build it.
Then everything is Ok.

---

I think there may be some weird bugs in conan resulting in above behavior. Maybe when build Qt lib, some file's permission mode has been changed. I don't know.